# Automating Jprofiler launching and data logging

Tags: user-interface, automation, jprofiler, java, gui-testing

I would like to know the package/library/API used to develop the Graphical component/GUI of Jprofiler. This information is required as I would like to automate the Jprofiler launching and data logging (testing)

Answer (score 0):

To profile automatically, use triggers:

http://resources.ej-technologies.com/jprofiler/help/doc/helptopics/config/triggers.html

if you do not want to add anything to your code, or the command line API:

http://resources.ej-technologies.com/jprofiler/help/doc/offline/api.html

if adding method calls to your code for profiling is OK.

Automating the JProfiler UI would be very difficult and is not a good idea.